# My default .json preferences altered in brackets

Tags: html, editor, adobe-brackets

[image: Default .json prefernces]

So these are the default preferences set for my brackets but it shows an error saying 
"Your preferences file is not valid JSON. The file will be opened so that you can correct the format. You will need to restart Brackets for the change to take effect."
Somebody, please help with a solution as I am not being able to use the live preview and many other relevant features of Brackets code editor.

Comment: Put the code in your question. Do not use a picture.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `comma` or `,` between each property. That's is the reason why it's not a valid JSON.You can use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON.Here is an example

```
{
    "brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": true,
    "brackets-eslint.useLocalESLint": false,
    "fonts.fontSize": "12px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
    "linting.collapsed": true
}
```

Comment: Whether this answer resolved your issue? if not comment below